# How to change an icon opacity with hover button

Tags: css, button, hover, opacity

I've been studying HTML and CSS for just a month, so my question is quite a basic one.

I need to make a white button with a grey outline, and the icon is set as 0.3 oppacity in its initial state. When the button is hovered, the icon turns black, but with no change in the button's oppacity.

I've tried two alternatives, changing figures and changing oppacity, but just what I get is the icon area active, not the whole button area.

```
<p><a href="#" class="button_facebook" ><img src="img/facebook_black.png" alt=""></a></p>
```

Comment: Please share more of what you've tried. And read in the StackOverflow Help center how to ask questions on this site, please.

Comment: can you add your css?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do can only be done when you have absolute control over the entire image. Which means, it can't be an image, but a web icon or svg image only. This way you have control over the colors. My suggestion is to make use of the [font awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) library. I demonstrate the difference by using both (image and icon) concepts here:

```
<div class="container">
  <p><a href="#" class="button_facebook" >
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNPKJ.gif" alt=""></a>
  </p>

  <p>
    <a href="#" class="button_facebook" >
      <i class="fa fa-facebook facebook-icon"></i>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  width:200px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
}

.button_facebook img{
  width:36px;
  opacity:0.3;
}

.facebook-icon{
  color: #000;
  background:#fff;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  padding: 8px 10px 6px;
  border-radius:50px;
  opacity:0.3;
}

.button_facebook:hover .facebook-icon{
  background:#000;
  color: #fff;
  opacity:1;
}

.button_facebook:hover img{
  opacity:1;
}
```

Here is a link to the [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQLbxB)

Let me know if I misunderstood.